# Compute figures

Tags: python, figures

Is there any way to compute figures as a sets of points in Python?

I mean, lets say that I define a circumference and a triangle and then, I define a new figure that is the result of the intersection of the triangle and the circumference. With that resulting figure/surface, I also want to add, or intersect more figures and get some properties from it, like the centroid of the resulting figure. Is there any library which I can do it? I think it's not possible with matplotlib...

For example:

```
c = circumference(0,0,1) #circumference at 0,0 and radius 1
t = triangle([0,0], [-2,2], [1,1])
new_figure = c & t
print (new_figure.centroid())
>>-0.5, 0.77
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at [shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely).

Answer (score 1):

I have found this [library](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/geometry/index.html). From the website we can see that:

> The geometry module for SymPy allows one to create two-dimensional geometrical entities, such as lines and circles, and query for information about these entities.